Is the license name and the URL to full license text sufficient for distributed software?
I have a software bundle that contains compiled executables under various free software licenses.
Is it safe to not include the full license text for every piece of software in the bundle, but just the name of the license including version number (for example, GPL version 2) and a URL to the full license text?
The bundle is expected to work in an environment where the internet connection is not available.
For some licenses (like BSD) there is a requirement to include copyright notices in the source file headers, but as I understand it, that is not applicable to compiled software.

"For some licenses (like BSD) there is a requirement to include copyright notices in the source file headers, but as I understand it, that is not applicable to compiled software." Why do you say this? "Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice"

I have seen more than one such bundle that has a folder for all the license documents, one copy of each. There would also have been documentation of which license applied to which bundle component -- maybe, but not necessarily, all in one place.  Of course, that's not the only way to organize things.

At least in the case of GPLv2, that would not suffice.  GPLv2 s1 is clear that "You may copy and distribute verbatim copies of the Program's source code as you receive it, in any medium, provided that you [...] give any other recipients of the Program a copy of this License along with the Program".  s3 goes on to say that "You may copy and distribute the Program [...] in object code or executable form under the terms of Sections 1 and 2", so the requirement applies to binary transfers also.
GPLv3 has a similar requirement in ss 6 and 4.
Whether anyone would care I cannot say, but the actual requirements are pretty clear, and the licence isn't all that onerous a document to transfer.
